# Swift: how to customize `UIPickerView` with two bars with buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, nib

In my app I am developing a customized `UIPickerView` to take photos. Following [this](http://makeapppie.com/tag/cameraoverlayview/) tutorial I have created a `.xib` file associated to its subclass of `UIView`. The result I have got up to now it in the following screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the "space" into which insert buttons and other stuff is entirely at the bottom while I would like to have it partitioned into two bars like the default mode:

[image]

so that I can add a "Cancel" button ad the top-left.
How shall I do it? This is my code up to know:

```
self.imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
self.imagePicker.delegate = self
self.imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
self.imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
self.imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen

//customView stuff
let customViewController = CustomOverlayViewController(
    nibName:"CustomOverlayViewController",
    bundle: nil
)
let customView:CustomOverlayView = customViewController.view as! CustomOverlayView
customView.frame = self.imagePicker.view.frame

presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {
    self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = customView
})
```

Comment: Don't copy-paste tutorials, this one explains how to use overlays and the overlay design is completely up to you, add as many rows there as you need.

Comment: @A-Live: yes but, how should I do to add rows?

Comment: Using interface builder or from code, whatever approach works better for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to understand...for example, I would try with xcode. What shall I add as row? I have tried with `bar button item` but it won't add...I may sound stupid but I need some more explanation

Comment: Did you sei constraints correctly in the xib?

Comment: I think so. Buttons are in the right position as I had set with constraints. Which further constraints should i set?

Comment: Bar items are supposed to be added on a bar, do you have one ? If not, add a button. There's tons of tutorials and documentation on how to add a subview and what constraints are needed, you can try to start with constraints suggested by Xcode if that is a problem.